# Creating table on the fly - CREATE TABLE... - using javax.persistence.EntityManager

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, ddl

I have a DDL statement to create a table on the fly

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE schema.table_1 ( AAA varchar, BBB double precision )"
```

I tried with

```
Query q;
/*1 try*/ 
q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);
q.executeUpdate();

/*2 try*/ 
q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("BEGIN " + sql + " END;");
q.executeUpdate();

/*3 try*/ 
q = getEntityManager().createQuery(sql);
q.executeUpdate();

/*4 try*/ 
q = getEntityManager().createQuery("BEGIN " + sql + " END;");
q.executeUpdate();
```

I'm getting errors while executing 1 or 3 try

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
```

or this error while executing 2 and 4 try

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I'm wondering if is there any other configuration I have to make to execute DDL routines to CREATE or DROP TABLE.

So my question is: How to create table on the fly, with NATIVE query (no Entities involved) using EntityManager interface?